# categorization/knowledge API that will tell that "apple" is a "fruit"

Tags: api, nlp

I'm writing yet another shopping list app, just for fun and personal purposes.

I'd like to automatically group items by their type without hardcoding all possible items and categories.
I'm looking for a public API that could tell for example that "cucumber" is a "vegetable" and "food" or that "toothpaste" is a "Hygiene product" or "apple" is "fruit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across two REST APIs:

- BabelNet
- Google Knowledge base

I found BabelNet better suited to my needs. It is better structured and has a vast range of supported languages.

```
// search for the word (aka sense)
curl "https://babelnet.io/v6/getSynsetIds?lemma=jab%C5%82ka&searchLang=PL&key=API-KEY&pos=NOUN" | jq

// search for descriptions/relations
curl "https://babelnet.io/v6/getOutgoingEdges?key=API-KEY&id=bn:00005054n&targetLang=PL" | jq |  grep "is-a" -a5

// get relation details
curl "https://babelnet.io/v6/getSynset?id=bn:00029758n&targetLang=PL&key=API-KEY&" | jq
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet), a lexical database which also contains lexical relations. So it will tell you that *apple* is a hyponym of *fruit*.

Comment: WordNet looks interesting however I didn't found public REST API for it :(
I found some similar projects (quite often based on WordNet) but either they are not free or are bugy.